# Dynamic Wizard Form Input coming as disabled

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make HTML template working with PHP.
Its located [here](https://uigaint.com/demo/html/anfra/version1/covid-1.html)

Since its HTML, I want load questions from My Database and So I have done coding like below

```
<?php 
                $i=0;
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {     ?>
              
                <div class="covid-test-wrap test-step">
                  <div class="test-progress">
                    <div class="test-progress-step">
                      <span class="step-number"><?php echo ($i+1)."/".$rowcount;?></span>
                      <svg>
                        <circle class="step-<?php echo $i+1;?>" cx="30" cy="30" r="28" stroke-width="4" fill="none" role="slider" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="50"></circle>
                      </svg>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h3><?php echo $row['question'];?></h3>
                  <div class="step-block">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="radio" name="package-plan" class="form-control" id="yes">
                      <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="radio" name="package-plan" class="form-control" id="no">
                      <label for="no">No</label>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="button">Next</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
               
             <?php
            
            $i++;
              }
        ?>
```

JavaScript for Next Button is like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

  $('.test-step .button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.test-step').next().addClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.test-step').removeClass('active');
  })

  $('.test-step .prev-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.test-step').prev().addClass('active');
    $(this).parents('.test-step').removeClass('active');
  })

})
```

Using above code, My All questions getting loaded completed and showing fine on press Next button but input radio working for only first question and in next questions I am not able to click any choice, its looking like disabled. I am not getting idea why its acting like this. Let me know if anyone here can help me for same.
Thanks!